# UITableView: after deleting rows and adding new ones, new rows are not selectable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a fairly normal `UIViewController` with a `UITableView`, I must have done this hundreds of times before. The only difference is my table can only have rows added or deleted while it is in edit mode (not sure if my problem is related to that).

The table is core data backed. I'm using Xcode 6.2, targeting iOS 8.2. The problem occurs on simulator and devices.

The problem is every time I delete rows, then add new ones, the new rows appear in the table as expected **but they are not selectable**.

`tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` are not called. The other rows are just fine.

This has been plaguing me for a day now and I thought it was a weird inconsistency at first, but once I identified the failure pattern it is 100% consistent.

Interestingly, after closing the app and restarting, the inserted rows are selectable, so I'm pretty sure the problem is in the table's internal state rather than anything to do with the data source.

I've tried everything I can think of, including liberally putting `[self.tableView reloadData]` calls after everything and explicitly re-setting `self.tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES`.

Some of the code is pasted below. (I've pasted all the methods I could think of that seem relevant to the bug.)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSLog(@"pages count %d", [self pages].count);
    return [self pages].count + (tableView.editing ? 1 : 0);
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row < [[self pages] count])
    {
        PageListTableViewCell *cell = (PageListTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kDefaultCellReuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        PageModel *page = [self pages][indexPath.row];
        // Configure the cell...
        cell.displayNameLabel.text = page.displayName;
        //cell.editing = [page.displayName isEqualToString:@""];
        return cell;
    }
    else if (tableView.editing)
    {
        AddTableViewCell *cell = (AddTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kAddCellReuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.hidden = YES;
        return cell;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row < [[self pages] count])
    {
        // ... normal selection behaviour
    }
    else
    {
        // add new row
        [self addPageAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}

- (void)addPageAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    // add row in core data
    NSString *pageID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"page-%ld-%@", indexPath.row, [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]];
    PageModel *page = [[PageModelController sharedInstance] addPageWithIdentifier:pageID displayName:@"untitled"];
    NSLog(@"Page %ld added, ID %@", indexPath.row, pageID);

    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        // Delete the row from core data
        PageModel *page = [self pages][indexPath.row];
        [[PageModelController sharedInstance] removePage:page];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your PageListTableViewCell do when you set the text? Does it add any views, change anyting etc... Does it have any transparent views which could be catching the users touches? Any constraint warnings in the console? It would seem from your description that the issue is with reused cells. When you remove, then add it will reuse an old cell for your new entry. Proof would be if you add first, can you select the new cell? If so then it is something to do with the reuse of a cell. Possibly you need to reset its content before setting new content?

Comment: The cell has a `UILabel` in it. I thought the issue was with the cell for a long time. But yes, in terms of your proof, I can add fresh rows first and select just fine. The issue only occurs after deleting: if I delete 5 rows, I have to add 5 rows back before I get one that I can select. But I'm not discounting cell reuse as a culprit either, since that would also happen when deleting/adding. Good call on the autolayout warnings, but I already checked that and there's nothing.

Comment: It sounds like the cell reuse is the problem for sure as if you delete 5, when you add 5 they will all be old cells reused. The 6th will be a new one and that seems to work fine from what you are saying. Would need to see you cell code to comment farther.

Comment: You shouldn't call `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` if you're making just one action inside.

Comment: Also, please show the code where you change between editing and non editing mode. You should do a `[self.tableView reloadData];` after you start/end editing mode.

Comment: @pteofil Thanks, but I only added the `beginUpdates` / `endUpdates` out of paranoia during debugging! And yes, I was doing the table reload when I switched in and out of edit mode. The problem was a missing `super` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found it - thanks to @Rory McKinnel for making me look closer at my custom cell implementation. It was doing virtually nothing because I'd stripped the guts out of it during my debugging efforts, but crucially it was still overriding `prepareForReuse` and was **missing a call to `super`**. Ouch.